# java.io.FileNotFoundException while deploying the code in the server

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

I have created a web service which will query the data base and save the file to a specific location. I have tested the code in the local system and its working fine. But when I am trying to put the code in the server it is showing file not found exception.
Below is the piece of code that I am running:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\ram_sahu/Hello.csv");
```

Could you guys please help me in this.

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an absolute path for the file which 'points' to the location of the file locally.
You need to put the path according to where it will be in the server.